# Pass Laravel blade variables to Angular

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5

I am looping through PHP values in my blade template. I'd like to apply a style only on the first iteration of the `foreach`, as such:

```
@foreach( $footer_columns as $index => $column )
                <div ng-class="{'pull-left': {{ $index === 0 }} }">
```

Getting error:

> Syntax Error: Token '}' not a primary expression at column 16 of the
>   expression [{'pull-left':  }] starting at [}].

There shouldn't be blade/angular conflicts as I have changed my Angular interpolation characters:

```
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
$interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't do `AngularJS`, but I think the issue you are having is in your evaluation. `{{ $index === 0 }}` will echo `1` when `$index` is 0, otherwise the output will be empty (and that looks like your error). I'm assuming you intend to echo 0 for all indexes that are not 0, so you will need to do:

`<div ng-class="{'pull-left': {{ ($index === 0) ? 1 : 0 }} }">`

Comment: Actually it should echo true and false

Answer (score 0):

I see your end result is JS object, so I would recommend doing it like that:

```
 <div ng-class="{'pull-left': '{{ $index === 0 }}' }">
```